# Update a Field, With Some Text, in the Newest (by id) Record

Tags: mysql

I have a table `my_table` and a column `name`.

I need a MySQL script to update the newest record (by id) with some text value to replace whatever is in `name` (which may be null).

I'm more of a MySQL user than query writer so here's my attempt.

```
UPDATE name in my_table SET name='some text'
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Small syntax error, try this

```
UPDATE my_table set name= 'some text'
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) from my_table)
```

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    UPDATE my_table set name = 'some text'
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) From my_table);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get error the error...  Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause